# My button is not automatically enable after clicking search button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have this code wherein the button will only enable when a particular input field has a value, when the search button is clicked the last name will remain on the input field, but everytime i clicked the search button, the clear button doesn't detect that there's a value in the input field that's why it was disabled unless you update the text inside the input field. Thank you

```
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="Last_Name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['search'])) {echo 
$_POST['Last_Name'];} ?>" required>
          
<button type="submit" name="search">Search</button>
<button type="submit" id="clear">Clear</button>

This is the script
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#clear').attr('disabled',true);
$('#lastname').keyup(function(){
if($(this).val().length !=0)
$('#clear').attr('disabled', false);            
else
$('#clear').attr('enable',true);
})
});
```

Comment: I've answered but also please format your question properly

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#clear').attr('disabled',true);
  $('#lastname').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length !=0)
      $('#clear').attr('disabled', false);            
    else
      $('#clear').attr('disabled',true);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="Last_Name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['search'])) {echo $_POST['Last_Name'];} ?>" required>
<button type="submit" name="search">Search</button>
<button type="submit" id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Hi sir, I tried your code but still the same. thank you

Comment: By default the clear button is disabled and input is showing php code, when I remove it or type something in the input, clear is enabled and by clearing the input again the clear button is disabled, is this the scenario you want to cover?

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you do it like in the following example ?

```js
const updateClearButtonState = () => {
  const isLastNameEmpty = $('#lastname').val().length === 0;
  $('#clear').attr('disabled', isLastNameEmpty);  
};

$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#lastname').keyup(updateClearButtonState);
  updateClearButtonState();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="Last_Name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['search'])) {echo $_POST['Last_Name'];} ?>" required>
<button type="submit" name="search">Search</button>
<button type="submit" id="clear">Clear</button>
```

The difference with your solution, is that I moved functionality of changing `clear` button state to a separate function.
And then I call that function immediately when `document` is ready.

This way the `clear` button should receive the correct initial state.